# What are the best ways to avoid overheating crashes?

Tags: crash, hardware-failure, overheating

I have a laptop that is getting old but my financial situation isn't the best. When I play some types of games that uses HQ graphics libraries like Call of Duty my computer is getting up to 90 degrees Celsius and then of course it's goes black and then crashes. I've tried under-clocking my processors and other software related attempts to fix this issue. Can anyone recommend the "best" way to prevent these overheating issues ?

Comment: Clean out the dust bunnies and replace the thermal paste. Check your fans are working properly.

Comment: Have you thought about getting a *cooling pad*? I have one for my laptop, because even on longer sessions it tends to get very hot and may even crash due to overheating. They aren't that expensive either and enhance the cooling of your laptop significantly (to the extent, that I can play games on it, without having it crash 5 minutes into a game).

Comment: I find that cooling the ambient environment a couple of degrees with my A/C helps keep my computers cooler. You would have to see how much that costs, comparing your power bill with the same month last year perhaps, but it's probably cheaper than a new laptop anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Get a can of compressed air take the covers off as much as you feel okay with blow it out and like the one user said invest in a cooling pad

Comment: Be careful with the compressed air. You may damage your fans if you don't hold the fan blades stationary when you are spraying them with compressed air.

Answer (score 0):

several things can be done:

1. as said - a fan-based cooling plate.
2. clean out your heat-sink... Most winblows boxes are marginal for cooling anyway - blow it out, and make sure you keep airways unobstructed.
3. cooling compound - Arctic Silver is the stuff to own..
4. don't play so long. (if finances are that bad, consider a regular break while you earn money to buy a better machine).
5. clean out your PC OS and delete extra software (i'm assuming this is a Win box of some sort (due to the lack of thermal issues on Macs as well as the ubiquity of gamers on Windows boxes)..

Comment: All is correct. Just wanted to add, that if it is a tower case, you need to install 2 more fans inside the case - on the front to absorb the air and on the rear side - to outputted hot air.
If you have a laptop, than buy a cheap cooling rack like Cooler Master L1 (R9-NBC-NPL1-GP) or Cooler Master I300 [R9-NBC-300L-GP]